# Flask: Два приложения одна база

Tags: mysql, flask

Есть сайт на Flask размещенный в интернете и админка к нему как отдельный проект на локальной машине.

Если из админки вставить новую запись в БД, то другое приложение увидит изменения только после перезагрузки uwsgi сервера. Как это исправить?

И вообще хорошая ли это идея, делать админку как локальный проект? Cхема такая: port knocking + ssh-тунель до сервера MySQL

Comment: С практической точки зрения идея не очень, ибо, во первых, не поадминить с мобилки (а может понадобиться), а во-вторых, свечение БД наружу, что даёт потенциальную возможность подбора/утечки пароля и слива БД

Comment: Но ведь порт закрыт в iptables и открывается только для моего ip если я постучусь port knocking`ом и автоматически удаляется через час

Comment: Мне стоило внимательнее прочитать конец вопроса -_- Тогда ещё остаётся первый пункт)

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение в [другом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974627/mysql-connector-not-showing-inserted-results)

Дело было в уровне изоляции транзакций, его нужно установить 'READ COMMITTED':

cnx.start_transaction(isolation_level='READ COMMITTED')

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял, вы **двумя** серверами баз данных **одновременно** обращаетесь к одним и тем же файлам, содержащим базу данных?

если так, то *mysql*-сервер, насколько мне известно, не приспособлен к такому использованию, и рано или поздно база данных может быть разрушена.

неконсистентность данных вы уже наблюдаете, осталось дело за «удачным» стечением обстоятельств.

Comment: нет, сервер баз данных один - удаленный, просто если данные изменит не приложение на этом сервере а другое приложение или я вручную введу запрос в консоли mysql то приложение этих изменений не видит до тех пор пока его не перезагрузить. Пришла в голову мысль в локальном приложении делать запрос по ssh на сервер и выполнять команду touch /my_project.ini, но это кажется костыль...

Comment: значит, программа — mysql-клиент (не знаю, что такое упомянутый *flask*, но, видимо, это он и есть) — кэширует данные, полученные от mysql-сервера (подозреваю, что это не результаты *sql*-запросов, а построенные на их основе некие структуры данных). возможно, у неё существует какая-то возможность повторить все запросы и сформировать структуры заново (ну, помимо перезапуска, которым вы пользуетесь).